# Elasticsearch: range query for count of nested array matches

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing **room** objects in an index like this:

```
{
"name":"room1",
"availability":"10",
"reservations": [
    {
        "start_date": "2019-09-12",
        "end_date": "2019-09-15",
    },
    {
        "start_date": "2019-09-17",
        "end_date": "2019-09-19"
    }
]}
```

Given a new **startDate** and **endDate**,
how can I match all rooms where **room.availability** is greater than the 
number of reservations that overlap with these dates?

Comment: I am not 100% what exactly is the ask here. Can you put another document with different values and put the resulting document (as if only those two documents existed in the `index`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a range query and a script query to only return the document according to your predicate ?

elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html